# Type 'Item' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to understand what this error means. I have defined a Type for an array of items and each item is a `string`.

When I wrap the `listItem` with an empty fragment the error is gone. Am I missing something? Because each item is a string only inside an array of items.

```
export type Item = {
  listItem: string;
};
```

```
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

import { Item } from '@typings/propTypes';

import { container, item } from '@lib/framer';

const UnorderedList = ({
  listItems,
  htmlClass
}: {
  htmlClass: string;
  listItems: Item[];
}) => (
  <motion.ul
    variants={container}
    initial="hidden"
    animate="show"
    className={`flex flex-col flex-wrap my-6 leading-relaxed ${
      htmlClass ? htmlClass : 'text-white'
    }`}
  >
    {listItems.map((listItem, index) => (
      <motion.li key={index} variants={item} className="flex gap-3">
        {listItem}
      </motion.li>
    ))}
  </motion.ul>
);

export default UnorderedList;
```

Answer (score 3):

`listItem` is of type `Item`, which is an object with a property called `listItem` which is a string. Objects are not valid React child elements, so `{listItem}` is invalid. The error is TypeScript's way of telling you that at authoring/compilation time before React tells you that at runtime. Perhaps you meant `{listItem.listItem}`, which would be valid because strings are valid React children.

Here's a simpler reproduction of the problem:

```typescript
import React from "react";

export type Item = {
    listItem: string;
};

// Doesn't work
const Example1 = ({item}: {item: Item}) => {
    return <div>{item}></div>;
};

// Works
const Example2 = ({item}: {item: Item}) => {
    return <div>{item.listItem}</div>;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljhgE8wk4BJGJPAXjgG9ycIXAA2wAM4wOXAFxxJUYADsA5hQC+FcgHptcACIQk4pQHJ4Ad2gBrcmghLJcAKLUU4EUgCMcXgAo+YE4QdTlA4LlpEIBKXwA+fkFhIhgAVyglOAAeABNgADc48K51LO08wo0tXTgAdRtxOwcnV3cwTwAmXzgAoJKwvpBI4PVY7gSBYTgU9MzcgqLBgDoxSSjS8oWq8iA)

> When I wrap the `listItem` with an empty fragment the error is gone.

Sadly, [that's true](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljhgE8wk4BJGJPAXjgG9ycIXAA2wAM4wOXAFxxJUYADsA5hQC+FcgHptcACIQk4pQHJ4Ad2gBrcmghLJcAKLUU4EUgCMcXgAo+YE4QdTlA4LlpEIBKXwA+fkFhIhgAVyglOAAeABNgADc4rLjwrnUs7SLtPMKNLV04AHUbcTsHJ1d3ME8AJl84AKCysKGQSOD1WO4EgWE4FPTM3IKS0YA6MUko8uqVuvIgA), but all it does is hide the problem from TypeScript. The problem actually remains, and React will complain:

```js
// Stack Snippets don't support shorthand fragment syntax,
// so we have to use the verbose form here
const Example1 = ({item}: {item: Item}) => {
    return <div><React.Fragment>{item}</React.Fragment></div>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example1 item={{listItem: "Hi"}} />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

That results in the usual "Objects are not valid as a React child" runtime error.

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {listItem}).

Comment: By doing like so: `<>{listItem}</>` problem is gone. When I console log listItem it returns multiple strings.

Comment: @Galanthus - Sorry, I meant to address that. I'll update.

Comment: @Galanthus - Updated, sorry again for not addressing that part of the question initially.

Comment: @TJ Error is gone but returns nothing when I do `item.listItem`

Comment: Doing this `{listItem.toString()}` also works. But each string has a WhatsApp Emoji + text. Is this maybe the reason?

Comment: @Galanthus - The default `toString` on `{listItem: string;}` will just show you `"[object Object]"`, so there's something about the contents of the `listItems` prop in your question that you're not telling us. Fundamentally, though, the answer is as above: You can't just use any object as a React child, you have to convert it to something renderable (like a string or other primitive, etc.).